# Green screening in Python using Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

i am learning green screenin in python i have understood this phase

1. Importing image and loading it in a variables
2. Loading pixels
3. Creating a new image

The part I want to understand better is where RGB values used for boolean statements come from.

I have watched a tutorial from Youtube but the video has no explanation, it's a follow-along kind of video. The part I am wondering is how one got the (RGB) values and determining which values to use when doing the boolean statements. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7TGHiExgp4&t=333s) is the video that I am referring to.

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEYun.png)

```
for x in range (0, width):
    for y in range (0, height):
        (r, g, b) = pixels_harvester[x,y]
        if r <= 150 and g >= 215 and b <= 60:
            pixels_harvester[x,y] = pixels_field[x,y] 
        elif r <= 145 and g >= 210 and b <= 145:
            pixels_harvester[x,y] = pixels_field[x,y]
        elif r <= 155 and g >= 210 and b <= 155:
            pixels_harvester[x,y] = pixels_field[x,y] 
        elif r <= 230 and g >= 254 and b <= 230:
            pixels_harvester[x,y] = pixels_field[x,y]
        elif r <= 164 and g >= 165 and b <= 84:
            pixels_harvester[x,y] = pixels_field[x,y]
        elif r <= 66 and g >= 120 and b <= 45:
            pixels_harvester[x,y] = pixels_field[x,y]  
        elif r <= 130 and g >= 200 and b <= 130:
            pixels_harvester[x,y] = pixels_field[x,y]  
        pixels_combined_image[x,y] = pixels_harvester[x,y]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider an image as a matrix (2D array, or list of lists) of pixels, on which we iterate with a nested for loop.
In a color image, each pixel has 3 color channels: Red,Green,Blue.

```
pixels_harvester[x,y]
```

will then be a pixel, represented in python as a tuple with R,G,B values to unpack.
The following if-checks are to determine whether we are checking a bright green pixel (you can see the `g >= ...`), and if so, substituting the pixel in `pixel_harvester` with the one in `pixels_field`, resulting in a "green screen" effect.

The video explains this a few minutes later, and besides this there are many more green-screening techniques already made and with better performace.